# How to check R function being used on Tableau Server without having to open workbooks via Desktop tool?

Tags: tableau-api, rserve

I am trying to generate a list of workbooks from Tableau Server which uses R functionality (calls R functions).
Is there a method that can be used from which I can identify workbooks which are using R without having to open them on Tableau Desktop?

Note: I am a Site Admin only. I do not have access to either the repository or the Server machine.

At the moment the only thing I am aware of is sign in via Desktop tool and check for the workbook to give you a warning message of the R function.

I need some method where-in I can check whether a workbook is connecting to R and calling R Functions without having to open each workbook on desktop.

Answer (score 0):

You can write in  "Description" field  like Tag 'R Connection" while create project on Tableau Server then access `Postgresql (Workgroup Database) - > Table (Projects) - >  Make a report` which projects has "R Connection" used.